# Pass the variable of one function into document.write - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
     <script>
        document.write(smsCount)  // i want to get "1" 
       </script>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

My script.js:

```
function sameer()  {
    console.log('function working');
    var smsCount = 1;
  }

sameer();
```

How to access variable which is located in my function name sameer.

Comment: make it `window.smsCount = 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to access variable which is located in my function name sameer.

You can't since visibility of `sameer` is limited to inside the function in which its declaration is.

**Either** make it visible to `window` (topmost level)

```
window.smsCount = 1;
```

Or, don't associate any `var`, `let` or `const` with it, its scope will keep propagating to the parent level till it is declared or it will be added to *global scope*

```
smsCount = 1;
```

Or return the value

```
function sameer()  {
    console.log('function working');
    var smsCount = 1;
    return smsCount;
  }

var smsCount = sameer();
```

Comment: how to make work this in inside one html file that means two <script tags> instead of separated script.js file?

Comment: This should work for both scenarios *two <script tags>* or *separated script.js file*.

Comment: can you make any fiddle? please its not working for me!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you get and what you tried?

Comment: instead of using script.js if i put this in function code inside new script tag inside my html, its showing undefined!

Comment: wait i wil send you fiddle :)

Comment: @MohamedSameer It is because your `document.write` is getting executed before `sameer()` is invoked. Try doing it after `sameer` is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `smsCount` outside the function in a global scope to get it accessed using `document.write`:

```js
var smsCount;
function sameer()  {
    console.log('function working');
    smsCount = 1;
  }

sameer(); 

document.write(smsCount);
```